# Running local copy of an old Wordpress site on MAMP

Tags: php, localhost, customization

Running local copy of an old wordpress site on MAMP

Hi there,

I need to update some stuff on an old WP site, which I plan on doing locally.

I am able to run the latest default version of Wordpress (4.9.5)  on MAMP, following the stages in this tutorial: https://managewp.com/blog/how-to-create-a-local-copy-of-a-live-wordpress-site

However, I when I pull down my Wordpress site via FTP and import the exported database, it does not run, instead it just trys to download the index.php file…

I figure this may be something to do with conflicting versions of Wordpress + PHP, but knowledge doesn’t stretch far enough to work out what. The original site (that I’m trying to run on localhost) has the following specs:

Wordpress version 3.1
Apache/2.2.34
PHP 3.5.2

I’m wondering what could cause this site not to run? I seem to not be able to run this version of Wordpress on MAMP…I have tried various .htaccess scripts (including the default WP one) and this does not seem to do anything. Nothing is in my apache or PHP logs either. Is there something I’m missing? What does one need to be aware of when trying to move an old wordpress site onto localhost?

Comment: I would try first the latest version of wordpress 3(wp3.9.24 came out in april), when you pull down you files from the server only copy the wp-content folder from the live site to the local installation. You will also need the settings from the wp-config file, and may need to edit them to match your local server db settings. .htaccess file may be needed, and mod_rewrite may need to be enabled in mamp(don't know the default settings of mamp). [This](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) article may have some useful information too.

Comment: I tried to do this, but I get an 'Error establishing database connection', despite importing my database from my remote server? I copied over the wp-config file also, and have both mod_rewrite on and the standard wordpress .htaccess?

Comment: Do you have on your local server a user that has the same login information as on the remote server? Because if you don't you either have to create one, with access to the database which you imported, or you have to edit the `wp-config.php` file to match your local database setup, meaning the `DB_USER, DB_NAME, DB_PASSWORD` and maybe the `DB_HOST` if it's not defined as `'localhost'`.